# Add:filedownloadaction listener issue

Tags: oracle-adf

I am using a adf file download listener for downloading the file. Page is getting refreshed on click of button which is causing error . how to handle partialsubmit request in adf like Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Your download listener is inside a button , try setting **partialSubmit to true** for button and let us know your jdev version too

Comment: Hi Ashish ,
Jdev Version:12c
 i have tried this partialSubmit true also, its not working.
You can recreate this scenario using unbeforeUnload javascript method in your page.

unbeforeUnload  function is calling twice.  
how to handle error & exception in adf:downloadACtionListener. when there is no file/bytestream present in managed bean then its always downloading a empty file. i have also throw JBOException but in this case all partial triggers are getting unregistered and PPR error is showing in fragment page.